# How to run some dart code in the background, every 15 seconds

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alarms

I've created app that checks the call log list every 15 seconds. I have used Timer.periodic() to achieve this. And everything works fine but only if app is not running in the background. After couple of minutes when app is in the background, the task which is scheduled by Timer.periodic is not executing anymore. I have tried to use android_alarm_manager https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager but it doesn't work at all. It's logging */FlutterBackgroundExecutor(11431): Starting AlarmService...* but then  nothing happends.

```
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';

void main() async{

  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), helloAlarmID, printHello);
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
void printHello() {
  final DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  final int isolateId = Isolate.current.hashCode;
  print("[$now] Hello, world! isolate=${isolateId} function='$printHello'");
}
```

Do I have any other possibilities to reach my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android limits background usage to every 15 minutes or so. There are several packages on pub.dev that can run code in background even when the application is closed. However i don't think any of them can run your code every 15 seconds.

Packages include:

background_fetch

workmanager

flutter_background_service

There are several more.

Comment: Thank You. But some apps are working in the background all the time. How it is possible?

Comment: User can prevent the app from sleeping by not 'allowing' app optimization in battery optimization settings. Even then Android may prevent your app from running all the time. There are some other settings as well such as put unused apps to sleep.

Comment: I've already did that. I mean i switch off battery optymalization on my app. But it's still killing the periodic proccess

Comment: May I ask which package are you using?

Comment: If You are asking about battery optmalization, I switched it off manually ( in my phone settings). To executing tasks I have used Timer.periodic and then android_alarm_service package. But it hasn't work